# Symfony Entity Param Converter not grabbing the correct route item

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I have a route that needs to grab a category and then a subcategory with a route looking like this:

```
    #[Route('/{slug}/{subSlug}', name: 'subcategory')]
    #[Entity('category', expr: 'repository.findOneBySlug(slug)')]
    #[Entity('subcategory', expr: 'repository.findOneBySlug(subSlug)')]
    public function subcat(Category $cat, Subcategory $sub): Response
```

I try to go to `/mtg/dmr` and I get a 404 object not found by @ParamConverter.
When I look in the profiler at the Doctrine logs, the system is looking in the right tables, but for both looking for `mtg` instead of first `mtg` and then `dmr`.  Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Where does that `#[Entity]` attribute come from, and what is its first parameter?

Comment: `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Entity`

#[\Attribute(\Attribute::IS_REPEATABLE | \Attribute::TARGET_CLASS | \Attribute::TARGET_METHOD)]
class Entity extends ParamConverter

Comment: So do you think the first parameter should match the controller parameter name?

Answer (score 1):

**Example from the DOC :**

```
#[Route('/blog/{date}/{slug}/comments/{comment_slug}')]
#[ParamConverter('post', options: ['mapping' => ['date' => 'date', 'slug' => 'slug']])]
#[ParamConverter('comment', options: ['mapping' => ['comment_slug' => 'slug']])]
public function showComment(Post $post, Comment $comment)
{
}
```

**So, in your cas you must have :**

```
#[Route('/{slug}/{subSlug}', name: 'subcategory')]
#[ParamConverter('cat', options: ['mapping' => ['slug' => 'slug']])]
#[ParamConverter('sub', options: ['mapping' => ['subSlug' => 'slug']])]
public function (Category $cat, Subcategory $sub): Response
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter names you put on the method must be the same as you put on the paramConverter names,

Document:

https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html

> The apply() method is called whenever a configuration is supported.
> Based on the request attributes, it should set an attribute named
> $configuration->getName(), which stores an object of class
> $configuration->getClass().

And following your code the objects are set on
$request->attributes as * category != $cat (your parameter) , subCategory != $sub ,
you will have null instead of your objects

**The names must be the same**

```
#[Route('/{slug}/{subSlug}', name: 'subcategory')]
#[Entity('category', expr: 'repository.findOneBySlug(slug)')]
#[Entity('subcategory', expr: 'repository.findOneBySlug(subSlug)')]
public function subcat(Category $category, Subcategory $subcategory): Response
```